# Allow access to salesforce from any domain using php

Tags: php, salesforce2salesforce

I am a newbie to Salesforce and need to allow access to it using my website.

I have gone through the documentation provided by salesforce but it did not help.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US

Actually I have developed a php website using codeignator and the requirement is, it needs to redirect users to salesforce.com for authorization, after authorization the application returns back to the website and from then I can add users as leads to salesforce directly from my website.

But when I try to connect to sales force as per the documentation given in the above link, it is throwing errors as shown below

```
error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration
```

I have signed up for a development account with salesforce.com but the users using this app will have enterprise edition and each user will have its own salesforce product, so how to implement this using one client_id or say my client_id and my redirect url which is defined in my salesforce account, is very confusing, I had posted this at stackoverflow main site but someone suggested to post here so I am writing it here.

Please help me with this how to allow access to individual salesforce accounts using php, any help is greatly appreciated, also please let me know if I am not clear with my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

@John Westenhaver Thanks for the reply, let me clarify more on this.

Actually there is a site called  myownsite.com, in this site I need to integrate salesforce contacts/leads, so that whenever I add contacts/leads to myownsite.com those are automatically added to salesforce.com. This functionality needs to work on individual login basis.

Eg: user1 can have his own contacts/leads and salesforce.com edition,
      user2 can have his own contacts/leads and salesforce.com edition and so on.

When user1 wants to add his contacts/leads in myownsite.com he will just authenticate himself using oauth on salesforce.com and redirects back to myownsite.com and based on the response I need to get data from salesforce.com like the contact fields etc and do mapping with myownsite.com and finally if any contact is added at myownsite.com it automatically adds to salesforce.com.

So for this I think I just cant ask each of the salesforce own to add call back to myownsite.com and also I cant ask them to create a connected app. They just need to signup with myownsite.com and they can integrate their existing salesforce.com app with mywonsite.com

I need to do something similar as described in this video from formassembly

http://help.formassembly.com/knowledgebase/articles/338997-salesforce-connector#create-object

Hope it is clear and please help or let me know if I am not clear yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does nobody knows how to achieve it? Or is it a wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex problem, and there are multiple possible causes, but when I got that error message when redirecting from Salesforce to PHP, it was because my callback URL was set incorrectly. (You want it this URL to point to the PHP page that the system should redirect to after authentication.)

If that's not the problem, please provide more information in your question.

Comment: Please check the question I have edited it for more clarification.